# Why isn't my if else statement working in controller [Rails 4]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, acts-as-votable

I'm trying to make the user be able to remove his upvote by re-clicking on the upvote button

Here's my controller

```
  def upvote
      if current_user.voted_up_on? @post
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        @currentUserLikes = PublicActivity::Activity.where(trackable_id: @post.id, owner_id: current_user.id, key: "post.like")
        @currentUserLikes.destroy_all
      else  
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        @post.upvote_by current_user
        @post.create_activity  :like, 
                             owner: current_user,
                             recipient: @post.user
      end
  end

  def downvote
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.downvote_by current_user
  @post.create_activity  :dislike, 
                           owner: current_user,
                           recipient: @post.user
  end
```

I tried placing the if else in the index but it became too complicated,
why isn't it working?
Note that currentUserLike is to destroy user's upvote action.
**and**
The upvote button is no more working, I didn't post the index because I didn't change it back when I didn't change the controller

Comment: What is not working? Did you check if it enters the if or else block?

Comment: The upvote button is no more upvoting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def upvote
          @post = Post.find(params[:id])
          if current_user.voted_up_on? @post
            @currentUserLikes = PublicActivity::Activity.where(trackable_id: @post.id, owner_id: current_user.id, key: "post.like")
            @currentUserLikes.destroy_all
          else  
            @post.upvote_by current_user
            @post.create_activity  :like, 
                                 owner: current_user,
                                 recipient: @post.user
          end
      end
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works, but found out the @currentUserLikes is not working, do you know why?

Comment: I suspect the problem is in the where() conditions. Use the console to find whether this condition returns what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like @post isn't set to a post when you check if the user voted it up. Try moving @post = Post.find(params[:id]) above your if statement.